# Does an SQL view duplicate data

Tags: sql

Under the hood, does a `view` create a duplicate/copy of data?

```
CREATE VIEW Deliveries
AS
SELECT o.OrderNo, o.OrderDate,
       c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Address, c.City
FROM Order AS o JOIN Customer AS c
ON o.Customer = c.ID;
```

I can query the view and filter the data in much the same way as a table using the following query:

```
SELECT OrderNo, OrderDate, LastName, Address
FROM Deliveries
WHERE City = 'Seattle';
```

Assuming that a `view` speeds up access to data, does a `view` does it by duplicating data? If so, does an `sql database` ensure data integrity by updating the `view` if the original table is updated?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've got product specific answer(s) below.)

Comment: not specific to any product. Just a generic question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on whether or not the view is *materialized*.  In a non materialized view, the view is basically just a wrapper for its underlying select query.  A non materialized view itself does not contain or duplicate any data.

On the other hand, a materialized view behaves more like a table than a view as described above.  In this case, all data in the view exists somewhere in its own place on the database.  In addition, if the data in the table(s) underlying the materialized view changes, then the view must be updated.

Comment: thanks. What is the benefit of querying a non-materialised view vs the table? How does the wrapper help?

Comment: Querying a materialized view (especially if it's indexed) can be very fast, whereas a non materialized view may be slow if its underlying query is not optimal.  It is a choice of sacrificing some space for speed.

Comment: Sorry, but my doubt remains - what is the purpose of unmaterialised views. They seem to work the same way as table. Materialised views duplicate data and thus work faster. Their purpose makes sense.

Comment: One use of a non materialized view is that instead of having to execute a complex query you can instead just do a simple `SELECT *` from a view.

Answer (score 1):

view is like just a shadow of the table ,
phycically it will not present in the database,
and yes if table is updated then the related view will also update.
(you have to run that view query when you feel data is modified)